# Creating an object from a custom type in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have made this type in  typescript and I want to use it to construct objects but I am getting confused and the only way have been able to make an object is by passing it through as a parameter of a function I am not really too sure how to make a constructor  or my type.

```
export type UserIdType = {
  userId: string;
  email?: string;
  title?: string;}
```

The only way I have been able to make an object is like this

```
const PersonalDetails = ({navigation}: Props,userId:UserIdType) => {

  userId.userId
```

what is the correct way for me to make an object using a custom  type I just want to make a default object that just has default values of each of the types in the type.

Comment: A type just describes the shape of an object for type checking. I think you are looking more for a class